# Java path to file in src/main/resources

Tags: java, maven

I have a maven module with the following directory structure and I want to get the path to `abc.access` in `abcManager.java.`

```
src
 |-main
    |-java
       |-org.abc.xyz
          |-init
             |-abcManager.java
    |-resources
       |-abc.access
```

I tried it using `abcManager.class.getResource("abc.access")` but it gives a null.

I went through the below questions but the solutions didn't work.

[How to get the path of src/test/resources directory in JUnit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28673651/how-to-get-the-path-of-src-test-resources-directory-in-junit)

[Can't get path to resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26609592/cant-get-path-to-resource)

Comment: you should use System.getProperty("user.dir"); to get the path of the current directory and concatenate the rest of the path you want

Comment: when you `getResource("abc.access")`, it looks it relatively to current class, so you probably need `/abc.access`, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13967307/reading-from-src-main-resources-gives-nullpointerexception?rq=1

Comment: @user7790438 I tried it by copying the path of the file and removing the user dir part, gave the the path as System.getProperty("user.dir") + "rest-of-the-path". Still didn't work

Comment: @RC. This didn't work either

Comment: There are three variants of solution, depending on the situation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56327069/715269

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was that I have not included the resource in the maven build in pom file. When I included the following it worked with `abcManager.class.getResource("/abc.access")`

```
<build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>abc.access</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
    </resources>   
</build>
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the javadoc of  `URL java.lang.Class.getResource(String name)` :

> Before delegation, an absolute resource name is constructed from the
>   given resource name using this algorithm:
>
> - If the name begins with a '/' ('\u002f'), then the absolute name of
>     the resource is the portion of the name following the '/'.
>     Otherwise,
> - the absolute name is of the following form:
>
>   modified_package_name/name
>
> Where the modified_package_name is the package name of this object with '/' substituted for '.' ('\u002e').

When you invoke :

```
abcManager.class.getResource("abc.access")
```

You don't prefix the path with a `"/"` character . So, you use the second way. 
It means that the resource should be located in 
the `org.abc.xyz.init` package (or folder) but it is not the case since the resource is located in the root of the `resources` folder.
In Maven, `resources` is the base directory for resources.
So you can get the resource by invoking the first way:

```
abcManager.class.getResource("/abc.access")
```

or you can also simply do it :

```
getClass().getResource("/abc.access")
```

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
String filename = "abc.access";
InputStream in = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filename);
```

Comment: or getResource(filename).

Answer (score 0):

Following should work.

```
InputStream resourceAsStream = 
                   abcManager.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("abc.access");
```

provided you are working inside an IDE (Ex. Eclipse). 
If you are trying this from commandline, you need to explicitely setup the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

class.getResource is local to the class, in this case package org.abc.xyz.init. You are trying to read src/main/resources/org/ABC/xyz/init/abc.access. Alternatively to the class loader which always loads from the classpath root you can also do class.getResource("/abc.access")